# Two way authentication with HTTPClient

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I am trying to make HTTP calls to a server that requires a two-way SSL connection (client authentication). I have a .p12 file that contains more than one certificate and a password. Request is serialized using protocol buffer.

My first thought was to add the keystore to the ClientCertificate properties of the WebRequestHandler used by the HttpClient. I've also added the keystore to my trusted root Certification Authorities on my computer.

I'm always getting a "could not create ssl/tls secure channel" when the PostAsync is executed. There's obviously something that I do wrong but I'm a bit at loss here.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
    public void SendRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            var handler = new WebRequestHandler();

            // Certificate is located in bin/debug folder
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificate.Import("MY_KEYSTORE.p12", "PASSWORD", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

            handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificate);
            handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

            var client = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("SERVER_URL")
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/x-protobuf");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf");
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

            // Serialize protocol buffer payload
            byte[] protoRequest;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, MyPayloadObject());
                protoRequest = ms.ToArray();
            }

            var result = await client.PostAsync("/resource", new ByteArrayContent(protoRequest));

            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                if (stringContent != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Request Content: " + stringContent);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
   }

        private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return false;
        }
```

**EDIT**

I don't even break into ValidateServerCertificate. Exception is thrown as soon as the PostAsync is called. Protocol is definitely TLS v1.

Client OS is Windows 8.1. Server is coded in Java (not sure on what OS it's running on. I don't have access to it. It's a black box.)

**Stacktrace**

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

There's no inner exception.

Comment: Who is the issuer of the certificate that is stored in the .P12 file? does the server trust such issuer?

Comment: It's issued by the owner of the server that I'm trying to connect to (they gave me the file).

Comment: Does ValidateServerCertificate return `true` or `false`? Can you put a breakpoint and check? In case it returns false, what is the value of sslPolocyErrors? try to always  return `true` from the method just to test if this solves the problem? Maybe your local machine does not trust the issuer of the server certificate?

Comment: Are you sure that the server uses TLS 1.0? Take a look at the [SecurityProtocolType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx). You can have SSL, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, or TLS 1.2

Comment: I don't even break into ValidateServerCertificate. Exception is thrown as soon as the PostAsync is called. As for the SecurityProtocol, I,m pretty sure it's TLS1 but I'll double check again.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Also, are there any `InnerException` for the exception?

Comment: What is the version of the operating system of the client?

Comment: There's no InnerException (null). I've updated the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: OS of client is Windows 8.1. Server is in Java (but I do not have access to it, nor is source code)

Comment: any updates on this? How you solve the problem, I run to the same as you ...

Comment: No, this issue was never resolved unfortunately.

Comment: Did you change the server URL from http to https and checked whether it is hitting the validateservercertificate method?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try changing your `security protocol` to `Ssl3`? Either case you would need to set `Expect` property to `true`. It will fix your error. Further you can explore [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/901183) to get more knowledge over passing client certificate for authentication.

```
public void SendRequest()
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        .....
    }
    ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try it but I still get the same error as mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to validate the Security Protocol being used when I came across this post.  I found that I throw an error prior to ValidateServerCertificate when I was using the incorrect Security Protocol.  (IIS 7.x defaults to SSL3.)  To cover all of your bases for the protocol to use, you could define all.
    `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same code base as you but instead of using

```
certificate.Import("MY_KEYSTORE.p12", "PASSWORD", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

I am using `X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet`

also I have installed the the root certificate to the CurrentUser/CA and is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following code?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Please it before your line of code

```
handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificate);
```